# adding a watermark image to an image

Tags: c#, image, watermark

I want to add a small, kind of fading out watermark image to all my images.

is there a way to do this in c#?

Comment: [This open-source module](http://imageresizingin.net) can apply watermarks dynamically through ASP.NET, as well as by command (from a Windows Forms, console, or ASP.NET app).

Answer (score 1):

You can compose images using `System.Drawing`

```
//1. create a bitmap (create a empty one or from file)
Bitmap bmpPic = new Bitmap(imgWidth,imgHeight);

//2. pass that bitmap into Graphics
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpPic))
{
    //manipulate the image
}

//3. save the bitmap back to a filestream
bmpPic.Save(imgFileStream,ImageFormat.Png);
```

Just make sure to dispose all resources used as System.Drawing uses unmanaged GDI+ resources