# Display Database value on an Image

Tags: c#, sql, database

I would like to know if there's a way to display database value on an image, like I have a image template of a certificate and i would like to display name from the database, cause I have like 1000 names and there Image have to be made, is it possible from me to make a c# app for that. Im sorry new to this I did searches but i can't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: you can watermark the image before displaying it!

Comment: is it web app or window app?

Comment: i have names in database and what to write them on the certificate template and save them separately.

Comment: windows app, I have and image and i would like to draw a string on it lets see how much i can get.

Comment: Check this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949526/adding-a-watermark-image-to-an-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by the GDI+ drawing in .NET. first, load your template image, then draw a string to it, then save it as a new image. load all the names from database and process them in a loop, that will be ok. what you must focus on is to find the proper drawing position and beautify the font, my sample is below:

```
private void btnDrawImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string templateFile = Application.StartupPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "template_picture.jpg";
        //customerize your dispaly string style
        Font ft = new System.Drawing.Font("SimSun", 24);
        Brush brush = Brushes.Red;
        //start position(x,y)
        Point startPt = new Point(100, 100);
        //names from database
        var nameList = new List<string>(){
            "scott yang",
            "Vivi",
            "maxleaf",
            "lenka"};
        //process image on every name
        foreach (string name in nameList)
        {
            string msg = "Welcome " + name;
            Image templateImage = Image.FromFile(templateFile);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(templateImage);
            g.DrawString(msg, ft, brush, startPt.X, startPt.Y);
            g.Dispose();
            string savePath = "c:\\" + name + ".jpg";
            templateImage.Save(savePath);
        }
    }
```

here is my result, I hope it is helpful to you.
[image: result of my test]
[image: result of my test]

Comment: appreciate your effort.

Comment: this is just Perfect ! thats what i really needed Thank you