# copy data from bitmap array into new array store data of bmp

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap, bitmapimage, bitmapdata

I work on bitmap i read header of bmp 24 bit per pixel ,width 320 height 240,offset start of image data in location 54,use c#

in location 54 in bmp array i access to data ,i store data in new array :

```
       struct pix  //structure for pixel in bmp image
       {
         public byte r;//Red
         public byte g;//Green
         public byte b;//Blue
        }; 


        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(opendialog1.FileName);

        string filename = opendialog1.FileName; 
        byte[] bmp = File.ReadAllBytes(filename); 

        int i=54;

        pix[ , ] bmpdata = new pix[img.Height, img.Width];  //create array of structure

        for (int row = 0; row < img.Height; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < img.Width; col++)
            {
                bmpdata[row, col].r = bmp[i];
                bmpdata[row, col].g = bmp[i + 1];
                bmpdata[row, col].b = bmp[i + 2];
                i += 3;
            }
```

is this correct method for copy data from bmp array  into new array for data only ,i use c# window form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not how you get the pixel data (color information).

Compare it yourself with the color defined at each pixel by calling `GetPixel(x,y)`

Also you could compare with this method:

```
        var pixels = new Color[img.Height*img.Width];
        for (int row = 0; row < img.Height; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < img.Width; col++)
            {
                pixels[row + col] = img.GetPixel(col, row);
            }
        }
```

If you just want the byte data, use `img.Save()` to save to a new `MemoryStream` for example...

Comment: ,ok thank you but after complete transom into var pixels ,how can I use "var pixels" as color or byte or what ?

Comment: `var pixels` is just an array of Color objects... What do you want to do with it?

Comment: can you give link or example  that help me how can I manipulate "var pixels in  array of Color objects,please

Comment: oO ok, that's something completely different... check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2927/Creating-a-Watermarked-Photograph-with-GDI-for-NET and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949526/adding-a-watermark-image-to-an-image or just google "c# how to create watermark"

Comment: thank you so much for your help,plz last question after i declare pixel as color object and store data of bmp in pixels how can i use it in RGB and other operation on image

Comment: If you have further questions, please mark this one as answered and ask another question. This would go into too much detail... And please ask you question in a way that we understand what you a trying to do ;)